# How can I target multiple css selectors in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am tying to apply some jQuery behaviour to two elements with their own css classes.

I am selecting the two classes like this...

```
$(".product-contain, .page-id-31").find("a:has(img)").fancybox({
```

However the script only works on the 2nd selector. I have tried various ways but cannot think of a proper way to do it, and I do not really wish to duplicate the code just for the other selector.

What is the correct way of applying the script to the above two selectors?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to call with `every` element `returned` by selector, currently `fancybox()` is only called with the element at `zero` index returned by the selector.

```
$(".product-contain, .page-id-31").find("a:has(img)").each(function(){
      $(this).fancybox({
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.each( [".product-contain", ".page-id-31",.....] , function(i, value){ 

     var el = $(value); 
     el.find("a:has(img)").fancybox({options});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma separation is the correct way to apply multiple selectors. The find function will attempt to match on all descendants of the context its applied to.

Your selector can be rewritten as: '.classA a.classC, .classB a.classC'  if selector matches your intentions then your filtering is correct.

Find will NOT match the context elements themselves.

Also, as noted, ensure that the function being applied applies to the whole set of results and not just the first. FancyBox will only apply to the first element in the set.  In this case you may apply the .each function to loop over all elements in the set and  apply fancyBox